# LyX type software

Tags: editors, ide

I am a big fan of LyX(I find typing up in TeX directly really annoying, I like being able to see my formulas), however are there any other programs that make it a lot easier to TeX too? I just want to see if there are others too so I can try them out. I am looking for LaTeX software which will work on Linux-Ubuntu.

(If it generates the PDF view directly that is a plus.. I know there is a paid versions that works that way)

Comment: A possible related question might be found here: [Latex Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).

Comment: Both Gummi and TeXmacs look intriguing, which is better? (also, is it possible to modify the output file directly?)

Comment: "What is like LyX but is not LyX"? is that your question? Why not stick with LyX? Is there some feature you think is missing or that you would like your LyX clone to have? Without more details I don't think this question is answerable...

Comment: I would like to be able to work directly in the PDF page. Basically I would like a WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install emacs with auctex, then you can see your equations also in preview.

Comment: If preview does not happen to be broken. :-) Vide [Debian auctex bug report - preview-latex is broken in squeeze](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=610714).

Comment: no problem for me with OpenSuSE ...

Comment: you said "see" equations in preview. Is it possible to "edit" in preview? That I think is the advantage I like with LyX.

Comment: no, that is not possible. However, inside LyX it makes only sense for not too much complicated math expressions. You can run into heavy trouble with the math editor!

Comment: can you give an example of an expression LyX cannot handle? I have not had issues with it. The only part I do not like is the formatting that can be a bit tedious to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [TeXmacs](http://www.texmacs.org/).  It is not exactly like LyX, it is not actually a frontend for LaTeX, but it can export LaTeX code, and it is heavily inspired by LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at Gummi ( http://gummi.midnightcoding.org/?page_id=4 ). It works well on ubuntu and compiles the code you write WHILE you write.

Answer (score 1):

The commercial software you are thinking of is Mackichan's Scientific Word/Workplace. The current version only works under Windows, but they have announced that the next version will work natively under Windows, Linux, and Mac OS/X. As far as I know, LyX and SW/SWP are the only programs that allow you to avoid typing TeX code.

Comment: There is also Bakoma TeX Word.